# Can I mark an email message with no-reply tag

Tags: email, exchange

My bos insists that I configure our mail so that when a message is received sender will get a auto-reply message confirming that his message was indeed received by our company.

So is it possible to mark such auto-reply message somehow in order to prevent sender's auto-reply mechanism from sending auto-replay to my auto-reply message so that I don't end up in endless cycle of sending and receiving auto-reply messages?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the auto-reply feature with my test accounts:

1. Enable auto-reply for the two accounts("**Ivan**" and "**T2**"):
   [image]
   [image]
2. Send an email from "**Ivan**" to "**T2**", then the result is the following:
   [image]
   [image]

In total, if both email sender and recipient enable auto-reply, sender will receive the auto-reply message from recipient, but sender won't send one auto-reply message to recipient any more. Besides, if two accounts are from different organizations(**Outside My Organization**), the result is same with the above one. Therefore, you don't have to worry about getting stuck in an endless cycle of auto-reply messages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most Out-of-office alerts will only send one alert per sending address per day / week. So this may not happen.